# What is the earliest mention of how often the Eucharist was celebrated?

Tags: church-history, communion, early-church, church-fathers

There is no explicit mention of how often the Eucharist was celebrated in the Bible.

What are the earliest historical documents that make reference to how often the Eucharist was celebrated?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The earliest indication may be in the [*Didache*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Didache), typically dated at the end of the first century.  It describes the celebration of the Lord's Supper in terms of the cup and breaking bread, and then says:

> But every Lord's day gather yourselves together, and break bread, and give thanksgiving after having confessed your transgressions, that your sacrifice may be pure. ([§14](http://www.earlychristianwritings.com/text/didache-roberts.html))

If this is a reference to the Eucharist, then we have evidence for weekly celebration less than 100 years after Christ's death.

In the middle of the 2nd century, [Justin Martyr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justin_Martyr) more clearly writes that the Lord's Supper is observed every week on Sunday:

> And on the day called Sunday, all who live in cities or in the country gather together to one place, and the memoirs of the apostles or the writings of the prophets are read, as long as time permits; then, when the reader has ceased, the president verbally instructs, and exhorts to the imitation of these good things. Then we all rise together and pray, and, as we before said, when our prayer is ended, bread and wine and water are brought, and the president in like manner offers prayers and thanksgivings, according to his ability, and the people assent, saying Amen; and there is a distribution to each, and a participation of that over which thanks have been given, and to those who are absent a portion is sent by the deacons. ([*First Apology*, §67](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/anf01.viii.ii.lxvii.html); see also [§65](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/anf01.viii.ii.lxv.html))

Comment: I get the impression that the Lord's Supper was originally observed every time a gathering ("where two or three gather in my name") of believers met. As Sunday became adopted as the standardized time to meet, it was most strongly associated with this day. Eventually, the ritual, since it was associated with the church, became less common in casual meetings. The Road to Emmaeus account may be an early evidence of this.

Comment: Also, [1 Corinthians 11:17-34](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Corinthians+11%3A17-34&version=ESV) strongly connects coming together to eat in general with the Lord's Supper.

Comment: @called2voyage That's a distinct possibility, but if so the transition to weekly seems to have happened pretty quickly from what I can tell from the writings of the apostolic fathers.

Comment: Well, given Paul's account there, it looks like it was already breaking down. They were not treating meals like the Lord's Supper.

Comment: The "Lord's Supper" as a phrase only occurs in that I Corinthinians passage. Based on the context, he's referring not to Eucharist/communion, but to a charity/agape feast. He scolds the Corinthians for abuses where the rich do not share with the poor and end up drunk. Then he indicates they are unfit to partake of the Eucharist "unworthy of the Body"

Comment: @called2voyage Agreed. Acts 2:42 and 20:7 may be biblical records of it being on any regular Sunday(note it's after the days of unleavened bread in ch.20).

Comment: @eques v. 22 and v. 33 specifically state that if one is hungry, they should eat before coming together. That would be a rather odd command if this were referring to a feast rather than to the communion. Also, vv. 23-26 would seem very out-of-place in such an interpretation.

Comment: @reirab He's referring to the excesses of the feasts making one unworthy to receive communion; that is, gluttony (drunk)  and avarice (leaving others hungry) "eat[s] this bread, or drink the chalice of the Lord unworthily, shall be guilty of the body and of the blood of the Lord. " (v 27).  The idea is the Paul is condemning these agape meals before Holy Eucharist and thus says if hungry to eat before "that you come not together unto judgment" (v 34). My bible's commentary also cites at this passage that [cont -->]

Comment: [<-- cont] these feasts were prohibited by the Council of Laodicea Canon 28: "It is not permitted to hold love feasts, as they are called, in the Lord's Houses, or Churches, nor to eat and to spread couches in the house of God." http://newadvent.org/fathers/3806.htm . So there was a practice condemned by Paul and by the Church later of eating in the Church before Eucharist "Or despise ye the church of God; and put them to shame that have not?"